I can't see any of my form values in the console upon submission
Why am I not able to see values in my console? Everything is correctly in place but the form values can't be seen in the console. I think it has something to do with the onSubmit function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
The form Schema using Zod:
/* creating a schema */
const formSchema = z.object({
  firstName: z.string().min(1, {
    message: 'First Name is required'
  }),
  lastName: z.string().min(1, {
    message: 'Last Name is required'
  }),
  email: z.string().email({
    message: 'Invalid email address'
  }),
  numberOfKids: z.number().min(1, {
    message: 'Number of kids must be at least 1'
  }).int({
    message: 'Number of kids must be an integer'
  })
});

The onSubmit function:
  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

The return statement (where the onSubmit function is being called) :
return (
    <>
      <Form {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          {/* FIRST NAME */}
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="firstName"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <FormLabel>
                  First Name
                </FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <Input {...field} placeholder="" />
                </FormControl>
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
...


<form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit, (errors) => console.log(errors)}>

it works, thanks to this, I saw that the number of kids was going through as a string when it was supposed to be a number. Thank you!

If the onSubmit function is marked as async, it's like waiting for something to finish before moving on. Check that your code waits for the form to be submitted completely before doing anything else.

After I added a log to my form, I was able to identify that numberOfKids was going through as a string when it was supposed to be a number. So it was just a type error.
